# 3D Rotation on QML Object

Tags: qml, transformation, image-rotation

I have a rectangular object that I would like to appear as if it has been rotated in 3D as shown in the picture below:

[image: 3D Image rotation with a top-down perspective]

The transformation that I'm applying on the object rotates it along the Y-axis as required, but I can't seem to figure out what other modifications I should make so that it looks like the object is being viewed from the top.

Here's the transformation I'm applying on the `Rectangle` object:

```
transform: Rotation{
            id: rotateImagePhoto
            angle: 45
            axis { x: 0; y: 1; z: 0 }
            origin.x: rect.width/2
            origin.y: rect.height/2
        }
```

The effect this has on the object is similar to what has been shown in the Rotation example in QML documentation [linked here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-rotation.html).

[image: Image rotation]

How should I change the transformation to get the desired result?

Comment: https://www.kdab.com/3d-block-building-game/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used the following [guide](http://www.enjoythisbeautifulday.com/how-to/isometric/) to create a isometric transformation to create the transform list. You could probably also create a [Matrix4x4](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-matrix4x4.html) that combines all the transformation steps in one matrix.

```
Rectangle {
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    color: "red"
    width: 300
    height: 300
    transform: [
        Rotation {
            axis { x: 0; y: 0; z: 1 }
            angle: 45
            origin.x: 150
            origin.y: 150
        },
        Scale {
            xScale: 0.5773
            yScale: 1.0
        },
        Rotation {
            axis { x: 0; y: 0; z: 1 }
            angle: -30
        }
    ]

    Text {
        text: "HELLO"
        color: "black"
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        font.pixelSize: 80
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is really the sort of thing I'm looking for! Additionally, could you please shed some light on how you calculated the `xScale` and `yScale` numbers and how they might be related to the `45` degree angle in the topmost `Rotation`. Also, how would the `30` degree number change in the bottom `Rotation` if the `45` degree angle in the top `Rotation` transform changes.

Thanks again :D

Comment: Unfortunately I can't explain how to come up width those numbers, I just used the guide I've shared to create the transformation. The guide also includes the transformation needed for the other sides. Also have a look at this tutorial http://jeroenhoek.nl/articles/svg-and-isometric-projection.html

Comment: If you can come up with a shear matrix you could probably skip the first rotation.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using actual 3D components to build this. Here I flatten a "#Cube" to give it a rectangular block appearance, and, to paint one side, I place a "#Rectangle" and slightly float it above the flattened "#Cube":

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick3D
Page {
    id: page
    background: Rectangle { color: "#848895" }
    Node {
        id: standAloneScene
        DirectionalLight { ambientColor: Qt.rgba(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0) }
        Node {
            id: node
            Model {
                source: "#Rectangle"
                z: 10
                scale: Qt.vector3d(1,2,0.2)
                materials: [
                    DefaultMaterial {
                        diffuseMap: Texture {
                            sourceItem: Rectangle {
                                 width: 64
                                 height: 64
                                 color: "#348"
                                 Text {
                                     anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                                     anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                                     anchors.margins: 10
                                     text: "F"
                                     color: "white"
                                 }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
            Model {
                source: "#Cube"
                scale: Qt.vector3d(1,2,0.2)
                materials: [
                    DefaultMaterial {
                        diffuseColor: "#348"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
        OrthographicCamera {
            id: cameraOrthographicFront
            lookAtNode: node
            x: 800; y: 800; z: 600
        }
    }
    View3D {
        anchors.fill: parent
        importScene: standAloneScene
        camera: cameraOrthographicFront
    }
    NumberAnimation {
        target: node
        property: "eulerRotation.y"
        loops: Animation.Infinite
        running: true
        from: 360; to: 0
        duration: 10000
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)